# Java How to get parameters that a object was declared with?

Tags: java, object, parameters, find

So I want to find out what parameters were used to create a object. How would I do that?
For example:

```
Example temp=new Example(1,2,3);
```

How do I find out what values 1,2, and 3 are, without manually saving them.

Comment: what is your reason or motivation for wanting this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A well defined object usually hides its members behind a set of methods.  If you need to discover how an object was initialized, you should add methods to its class that allow those details to be determined.  And yes, this would involve at least saving these details as part of the object's initializer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  (Indeed, if you could, that would cause a number of bad things to happen. Not all constructor arguments are meant to be saved.)

Save them manually as fields in the class, like you normally would.

Comment: Dang it. That makes life so much more difficult.

Comment: It can be done if the data fields are public or, in some cases, protected, right?

Comment: I thought by "not saving them," the OP meant that they didn't want to have to define the fields in the class at all.

Comment: Ah ok. (need more chars to post comment)